# Using ng-class with property/value pair expression

Tags: angularjs, class, angularjs-ng-repeat, expression, ng-class

I want to be able to use ng-class to trigger a class based on the true/false value of the expression. I know how to do this if it just checking for a property's existence, but what I want to do is input an expression to say 'the **value** of this property is **this**'.

So, if I was trying to link a colour to a football player's position, for example, I would like to say:

```
<p ng-class="{'green': player.position: gk}">
```

This doesn't work though.

Is there a way of doing this? If so, where am I going wrong?

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulos3000/U3pVM/22917/

In this example I want any player who has a position of "gk" to be green.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<p ng-class="{'green': player.position == 'gk'}">
```

This should work :)